# Significant p value for Mann-Whitney U test but low AUC

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, auc, scipy

How is it possible that for two sample sets I'm getting a low p-value, but also a low AUC value (just below 0.5)?

To compute the P-value I'm looking at the second outputted value of the function here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mannwhitneyu.html

For the AUC I'm using the same function's first outputted value divided by the product of the sample sets lengths.

And here is a boxplot of the two series:

[image: boxplot of the two series]

Comment: Because this question is at least partly tied with a specific software/language which some people potentially able to help you don't use - you _should give a data and the results_ they produce. So that people can try to reproduce the results in the software they know.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the right statistic? - you might be calculating the area *above* the ROC curve.

Comment: Yeah but it's still close to 0.5 so same same.

Comment: @ttnphns I've added a boxplot. I don't really know how to transfer the sample sets.

Comment: What sufficiently large sample sizes the area under the receiver operating characteristic curve (AUC) could be "close" to 0.5, yet the one-sided p-value for the Mann-Whitney test "low" (as long as the AUC is greater than 0.5). Another thing to check might be exactly how the statistic's computed - there are some different versions.

Comment: "what sufficiently large samples..." -> "with sufficiently large samples..." ?

Comment: @Uri: Yes - sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looking at the boxplot heavily indicated that @Scortchi is correct with his comment. The number of outliers alone indicate that you have a very high sample size, so a very high power to find differences. This means you have strong evidence for a very small discrimination, which is usually not of high interest (practically speaking).

Mann-Whitney p-values (using the normal approximation) vs AUC for some different sample sizes ($n_1,n_2$):

[image: AUC vs p-value]

Comment: If I choose a random subset of 500 samples of each set I see some correlation between AUC and the p-value, but can still get a significant p-value (0.03) and low AUC (0.53)

Comment: Could you explain "a very high power to find differences"?

Comment: @Uri: There should be no question of a *correlation* between AUC & the calculated p-value for given sample sizes: An observed AUC $c$ together with sample sizes $n_1$ & $n_2$ *determines* a p-value of $1-\Phi\left[n_1n_2 \left(c - \frac{1}{2}\right) / \sqrt{\frac{n_1n_2(n_1+n_2+1)}{12}}\right]$ where $\Phi(\cdot)$ is the standard Gaussian distribution function. With both sample sizes at 500, an AUC of a little over 0.53 would give a p-value of 0.03, so your calculation seems correct.